# multi boot: xp + xp + xubuntu, how to?

Tags: windows-xp, grub, multi-boot, xubuntu

My laptop (with a single harddrive) currently has xp + xubuntu dual boot.

I want to make that triple boot: xp + xp + xubuntu

Please don't ask why, take it as given.

How can I accomplish this triple boot? I tried using gparted to add a partition (worked!), used dd to clone the xp install to the new partition (worked!), edited grub (my bootloader) to list a third entry pointing to the correct device (worked!). But regardless of which of the two xp entries in grub I select I still get booted into one and the same XP. The files for the other XP show up under D: so I know they're there alright. I have edited the boot.ini on the new partition so everything looks to be in order.

What do I need to do to change that and make both xp instances bootable in this scenario?

menu.lst:

```
  default 4
  timeout 10
  title     Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-15-generic
  ... 
  title     Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-15-generic (recovery mode)
  ... 
  title     Ubuntu 9.04, memtest86+
  ...
  title     Other operating systems:
  root

  # on /dev/sda2
  title     Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition
  rootnoverify  (hd0,1)
  savedefault
  chainloader   +1

  #  on /dev/sda3   
  title     XP 2
  rootnoverify  (hd0,2)
  savedefault
  chainloader   +1
```

fdisk -l :

```
     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1            5117        5359     1951897+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
  /dev/sda2   *           1        2558    20547103+   7  HPFS/NTFS
  /dev/sda3            2559        5116    20547135    7  HPFS/NTFS
  /dev/sda4            5360        6986    13068877+   5  Extended
  /dev/sda5            5360        6986    13068846   83  Linux
```

Comment: please post your Grub's config file (menu.lst or grub.cfg) and perhaps a partition listing (*fdisk -l*).  which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question and add those two outputs to it using the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
 #  on /dev/sda3   
 title     XP 2
 map (hd0,2) (hd0,1)
 map (hd0,1) (hd0,2)
 rootnoverify  (hd0,2)
 savedefault
 chainloader   +1
```

This should swap the two XP-Partitions. Please verfiy your changes first using `sudo update-grub`.